# How can I use Sweetalert with CSS applied?

Tags: html, css, sweetalert2

I am trying to use the Sweetalert 2 (https://sweetalert2.github.io/) library to pop up a warning message on a page. Even, I think that I am linking the CSS file correctly, the warning message is shown with plain text. The CSS rules are not applied.

I have prepared a minimal page with just the warning message to rule out other reasons, but nothing has changed.

This the head section.

```
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8/dist/sweetalert2.min.css">
</head>
```

And this is the body.

```
<body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            Swal.fire({
               type: 'question',
               title: 'Oops...',
               text: 'Something went wrong!',
               footer: '<a href>Why do I have this issue?</a>'
            })
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

I expect the warning message with CSS applied, but is shown with ugly fonts with no CSS. I checked the console with F12 and there was no error. The browser can reach all required files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your implementation. SweetAlert2 uses `font-family: inherit;`, so it will take parent font.

To solve this, you just need to set the `font-family` for `<body>` accordingly.

```js
Swal.fire({
  type: 'error',
  title: 'Oops...',
  text: 'Something went wrong!',
  footer: '<a href>Why do I have this issue?</a>'
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8"></script>
```

Comment: This solved the issue Nidhin. Thank you. But I have seen that the Sweetalert2 does not go very well with Bootstrap. The CSS of Bottstrap overrides Sweetlart and there are further actions to be taken to correct this issue as well. I am looking into that now, but your answer was accurate.

Comment: Worked for me too.